Router occasionally losing internet connection: Destination Net Unreachable
Earlier this year when I moved into a new apartment, I bought a Wavlink AC2100 Gigabit Router. From time to time, I would get disconnected from an online game that I play. Didn't think much of it, as you're always gonna get a little lag now and then. Eventually I realized that it was more than just occasional; it happened on a more-or-less daily basis and it was never accompanied by lag or any disruption to other online activity.
I started leaving a ping window running in the background so I could see if anything was going on as my connection dropped. And it was not from timeouts but a single Destination Net Unreachable message:
64 bytes from a23-197-14-37.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.197.14.37): icmp_seq=1868 ttl=55 time=62.8 ms
64 bytes from a23-197-14-37.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.197.14.37): icmp_seq=1869 ttl=55 time=51.6 ms
From wavlogin.link (192.168.10.1) icmp_seq=1870 Destination Net Unreachable
64 bytes from a23-197-14-37.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.197.14.37): icmp_seq=1872 ttl=55 time=60.3 ms

I found that it happened regardless of which computer I'm using, which OS, whether it's connected via Wi-Fi or Ethernet, and whether I ping the game server or a random website. It's always very brief (1-2 seconds) and immediately recovers on its own before any video/music I'm streaming at the time gets interrupted. I further discovered that if I hook directly into the modem instead of using the router, I never experience these drops, ruling out a generically unreliable internet connection on Spectrum's end.
Before I give up on this and buy a new router, I am trying to eliminate any possibility that this is an easily fixable issue. So far I have tried switching cables, updating the router's firmware, changing my PC's link negotiation from Auto to Manual Half Duplex, and power cycling the modem and router many times. I'm hoping for anything else I can try before concluding that it's just a physical flaw with the router.

Does the router have any sort of "system log" section in its config area? Does it have any place where it would show Ethernet port status (i.e. the currently-negotiated link mode)? Reconfiguring Ethernet negotiation on your PC was useless if it is the router that loses connection to the modem, not the PC (although with modern-day equipment, disabling Ethernet autoneg is never the right solution to begin with), but more importantly, it would be useful to see what is actually being negotiated, for example, does the router's Ethernet port leading to your modem manage to get 1Gbps mode?

@grawity_u1686 Unfortunately the router does not seem to have any kind of system log. Device Status shows Internet Status as "Current Mode: Router(DHCP)" and "Internet: Connected". Nothing as specific as the negotiated link mode.

That's unfortunate – it's not even that specific a parameter. (Sometimes the port's LED color might indicate the mode...) Does the modem show anything for the corresponding LAN port, then? It would usually be the same for both ends of the cable. Have you tried changing the router---modem cable specifically (not the PC---router one)? Does the ethernet cable go in parallel with any power cable?

The modem's port is steady green on the left and flashing amber on the right, and the manual says that's a 1Gbps connection. Router and modem are only inches apart, no issue with anything running parallel to the cord. I can't say for 100% that I've tried all 3 cables between router and modem; I guess that will be the next and final thing I try. Thank you for all your advice, I really appreciate it!
